# Convert coordinate data to legacy coordinate pairs in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, location

I have a collection that stores location data in the below format:

```
{ "Place": "xyz", "Location": { "long": 42.34, "lat": 73.59 } }
```

I need the above Location data to be transformed to legacy coordinate pairs using aggregate query. This is what I need as output:

```
 {   "Place": "xyz",   "Location": [42.34, 73.59] }
```

How will I be able to achieve this? The order of the coordinate pair is very strict, i.e longitude should come first then the latitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible with mongoDB 3.2 using [**`$concatArray`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/#concatarrays-aggregation) feature. So the aggregation will look like:

```
db.locations.aggregate({
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$Place",
        "Long": {
            "$push": "$Location.long"
        },
        "Lat": {
            "$push": "$Location.lat"
        }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "Places": "$_id",
        "_id": 0,
        "Location": {
            "$concatArrays": ["$Long", "$Lat"]
        }
    }
})
```

The order is also preserved using $concatArrays

Answer (score 0):

Use mongo [$setUnion](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) query as below

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$Place",
        "Long": {
            "$push": "$Location.long"
        },
        "Lat": {
            "$push": "$Location.lat"
        }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "Places": "$_id",
        "_id": 0,
        "Location": {
            "$setUnion": ["$Lat", "$Long"]
        }
    }
}).pretty()
```

> $setUnion performs set operation on arrays, treating arrays as sets. If an array contains duplicate entries, $setUnion ignores the duplicate entries. $setUnion ignores the order of the elements.

From above links it mentioned that `setUnion` ignores the order. Hence it shows some wrong results. For finding this I tried many mongo queries but not succeed. Then using mongo [forEach](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) method it shows the expected output

```
  db.collectionName.find({
      "Location": {
          "$exists": true
      }
  }).forEach(function(data) {
      locationData = [];
      locationData.push(data.Location.long);
      locationData.push(data.Location.lat);
      var document = {
          Place: data.Place,
          Location: locationData
      };
      printjson(document);
  })
```

Comment: How will I ensure the order of Location in the result?

Comment: Location array contains first is `lat` and second is `long` using this `"$setUnion": ["$Lat", "$Long"]` in project

Comment: I am not getting lat as first, instead I am getting long as first. I am using mongoDB version 2.6.1

Comment: @cj0809 using mongo `setUnion` the order of array changed, I updated new code. Check once may be it will help you.

Comment: I have to achieve this using aggregation framework since there will be millions of data and I need to avoid looping of documents from middle ware side.